# Can't scrape elements using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to get scrape data from the Microsoft site : https://jobs.careers.microsoft.com/global/en/search?lc=Israel&l=en_us&pg=1&pgSz=20&o=Relevance&flt=true&ref=cms

I have tried to get "see details" button in many ways (XPATH,CLASS and more..) and I don't get were I am wrong.

My code for "By.Class" scraping :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"css-470")))
```

My code for "By.Xpath" scraping :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
     elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="job-search-app"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/button')))
```

I got an error :

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong selector.

Each job is placed in container that has unique selector `[data-automationid=ListCell]`

Each See Details button has unique class part `[class*=seeDetails]`

So, to locate it you need just to combine this 2 css selectors.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://jobs.careers.microsoft.com/global/en/search?lc=Israel&l=en_us&pg=1&pgSz=20&o=Relevance&flt=true&ref=cms')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-automationid=ListCell] [class*=seeDetails]")))
elements[0].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the lowest level unique value, which means the selector which uniquely identifies your element (or elements) at the lowest level, always go with that. In your case, every 'See Details' link has a text 'seeDetails' inside their 'class' attribute which should be unique(lowest level) enough to identify all 'See Details' link in the page. You can use css selector and use the "*=" symbol to select the substring from the class attribute. So your final locator will be

`[class*='seeDetailsLink']`